# Getting DTMF signals when receiving a call on Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, dtmf

Is there any way to receive and identify DTMF signals when you get a phonecall?
I found these two functions ([extractNetworkPortion](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#extractNetworkPortion%28java.lang.String%29) & [extractPostDialPortion](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#extractPostDialPortion%28java.lang.String%29)), but I can't seem to get DTMF signal send by phonecalls.

Also, what is the shortest delay you can have for sending DTMF signals when calling someone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible in standard Android platform (as of the latest version,  3.1)

Comment: Does that means android sipmanager doesnt have any feature to receive dtmf tone

Answer (score 0):

It is not in SDK but you can make it.

Look at this project :

http://code.google.com/p/dtmf-decoder/source/checkout